# Squares under Lowner order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Suppose that $A, B$ are symmetric, positive definite, real matrices with the property $A \geq B$. Let $M$ be another symmetric, positive definite, real matrix (assumed to be of compatible dimensions). Is the following inequality true:
$$
AMA \geq BMB
$$
Of course, it is true for scalars, but I don't see an easy proof for matrices.

Comment: The answer is no, even in the case that $M=I$.

Comment: What is an example of that? I am only familiar with counterexamples when $A-B$ is positive definite, a weaker condition than requiring both $A, B$ positive definite and $A > B$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, as seen from Example V.1.2, in Matrix Analysis, by Bhatia.

Reproduced below:

Suppose
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then note: $A - B = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right) \geq 0$. Additionally, it is easy to see that $B \geq 0$, and so $A \geq B \geq 0$.
On the other hand,
$$
A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix} \quad \mbox{and} 
\quad 
B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, with $M = I$,
$$
AMA - BMB = A^2 - B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \not \geq 0,
$$
since it has determinant $-1$.